# Use local geojson file in php/ajax routine

Tags: php, json, ajax, curl

I've been using cURL and ajax to load data from APIs. I also have a local geo.json file. I did

```
function borders() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "libs/geojson/countryBorders.geo.json",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
          //my code 
        }
    })
}
```

While this works, my tutor told me to not access the geojson file in the javascript file, but to break it into a PHP and ajax routine. My question is: how would I do this? For APIs, I've saved the API calls to a variable and used curl methods to decode the data, however, I'm not sure what to do with local files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jquery automatically change select box value when another select box change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758352/jquery-automatically-change-select-box-value-when-another-select-box-change)

Comment: hi WebPajooh! Sorry, I was going to ask a related to the select box but I realised where I was going wrong while I was typing it out. I think that StackOverflow saved it as a draft and I didn't realise that I didn't change the title of the question when asking this new questionn

Comment: I found this post which answered my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68023021/making-ajax-post-requst-to-php-routine-to-local-file